# Tableau - Is there a way to drill down by clicking on the line?

Tags: tableau-api

I have the following chart

[image]

I have created a parameter called `IO OR LINE` with two values: `IO` and `LINE`
then created a computed item called `IO DRILL DOWN` which is defined as:

```
if ([IO OR LINE] == 'IO') then [IO] else [Line Item] end
```

where the `IO` and `Line Item` are two dimensions

In the parameter drop down, if I choose `LINE`, I will get the chart

[image]

**My question:** I want to do the operations above but by clicking on the blue line in the first chart which will drill down as shown in the bottom chart? I don't like the parameter drop down solution

Answer (score 0):

You could get this effect by:

1. generating 2 identical dashboards, one with the single line and
   the other with the detailed view
2. Set up a Filter Action for when you click on the blue single line it takes you to the other dashboard with the multi-lines. If the dashboards are    exactly the same and the performance is quick, this will give you what you are describing but it's a bit of an illusion.

At first, I thought you could do this somehow with layout containers and filter actions, but I got stumped when it came down to hiding the original view. https://www.interworks.com/blog/dwyers/2012/05/10/using-layout-containers-hide-views-your-tableau-dashboard